# SVN Rename file as a directory

Tags: file, svn, repository, rename

I need to use the name of a particular file as a directory name, and that file to be moved inside brand new directory.

My repo look like this right now:

```
file1
file2
dir1/
  dir1file1
search
source_code2
```

And I need to get this:

```
file1
file2
dir1/
  dir1file1
search/
  search_contents
source_code2
```

The operations that I need to do are:

```
 mv search search_contents
 rm search
 mkdir search
 mv search_contents search/
```

I suppose that I can do:

```
 svn move search search_contents
 svn del search
 mkdir search
 svn add search
 svn move search_contents search/
```

Does it make sense?

How svn will deal with several commands over a single file name? (without doing a commit) Or should I make intermediate commits?

Comment: Yes it makes sense. It _may_ be fine. Yes, best to be safe.

Comment: I'd use intermediate commits to avoid any issues.  Subversion may get a little bit upset with multiple moves / renames on the same file/dir in one commit.  I'm not sure you need the `svn del search` either, as `svn move search search_contents` essentially deletes search and adds search_contents

Comment: @John You're right, that is an unnecessary step, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to do that without committing and updating in-between, you'll get a message like this:

> svn: Can't replace 'search' with a node of a differing type; the
>   deletion must be committed and the parent updated before adding
>   'search'

Just change your list of svn commands to this:

```
svn move search search_contents 
svn commit -m "Renamed file"
svn up
mkdir search
svn add search
svn mv search_contents search
svn commit -m "done"
```

Comment: I just wanted to be sure, because the intermediate commit would leave an inconsistent application :( I think I'll just have to say that in the commit message.

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately, I don't know how you can avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Doug, It worked as spected :) I just left a big warning message on commit :P

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that those steps can be done in one [single commit](http://paste.opensuse.org/29937545):

```
# variant 1
svn move search search-newname
mkdir search
svn add search
svn move search-newname search/search
svn commit -m "magic"

# variant 2
svn delete search
mkdir search
svn add search
svn copy "^/search@3" search/
svn commit -m "more magic"
```

Thing is that I wasn't sure and I didn't want to mess up the repo, the credits to this answer go for tacit on #svn channel on irc.freenode.net

Also, I have to thank to danilsh and wayita for mention svnmucc. [svnmucc](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/svnmucc/) is a tool that can combine several comands in a list (cp, mv, rm, etc.)